# Formik get selected option as boolean

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, formik, ionic5

I want to check if a selectedOption is "group", and then set the `group` value to true, else set it to `false`. The Form Component goes thus:

```
<Formik
            initialValues={{
              group: null,
              firstName: "",
              surname: "",
              mobile: "",
              email: "",
              policyId: "",
              groupSize: "",
              names: "",
            }}
            onSubmit={(data, { setSubmitting }) => {
              setSubmitting(true);
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(data);
              }, 3000);
            }}
          >
            {({
              values,
              handleBlur,
              handleChange,
              handleSubmit,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              setFieldValue,
              touched,
            }) => (
              <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <IonItem className="f-reg ion-no-padding form-label mb-3">
                  <IonLabel className="sec-color fw-light">
                    Please select
                  </IonLabel>
                  <IonSelect
                    name="group"
                    className="fw-light sec-color"
                    placeholder="Select type..."
                    // trying to check in the onChange Method
                    onIonChange={() => {
                      values.group === true
                        ? setFieldValue("group", values.group)
                        : setFieldValue("group", !values.group);
                    }}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                  >
                    <IonSelectOption value={values.group === false}>
                      Individual
                    </IonSelectOption>
                    <IonSelectOption value={values.group === true}>
                      Group
                    </IonSelectOption>
                  </IonSelect>
                </IonItem>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
```

all i want to return in the form submitted is either group is true or false based on selectedOption

Comment: You don't refer to a selected option inside `onIonChange` method, please pay attention

Comment: i don't understand please

Comment: Try
`onIonChange={(e) => { setFieldValue('group', e.detail.value === 'group') }}`

Comment: not working sir

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-forms-formik?file=src%2Fpages%2FTab1.tsx